# PyroCMS 3 on win 7

Tags: laravel, pyrocms

i try install PyroCMS 3 on win 7 x86, i download it with composer :

```
composer create-project pyrocms/pyrocms=3.0-beta1 --prefer-dist
```

all seems correct, but then i go on localhost/pyrocms i see only structure of folder, i try  localhost/pyrocms/install or localshot/pyrocms/index.php
but when i visit localhost/pyrocms/public a get this errot

> Warning: require(C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

it seems like premission issue but on win? And the autoload.php file exist.

When i try `composer update` i get this error:

> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   faile d to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap\ autoload.php on line 17
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0000     119776   1. {main}() C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\artisan:0
>       0.0010     121632   2. require('C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.ph p')
>   C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\artisan:16
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstra p/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:/laragon/bin/php/php-5.6.13/PEAR') in
>   C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0000     119776   1. {main}() C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\artisan:0
>       0.0010     121632   2. require('C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\bootstrap\autoload.ph p')
>   C:\laragon\www\pyrocms\artisan:16
>
> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event
>   returned wit h an error
>
> [RuntimeException]   Error Output:
>
> update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--lock]  [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no- progress]
>   [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
>   [--prefer-stable] [--pre fer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]

How can i fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot use

> php artisan dump autoload

my bad.

Comment: please add details on how you actually fixed your problem so this answer can help others in the future